# How to undo disk partitioning

Tags: 16.04

when i install ubuntu alingside windows I had resized windows partition and now windows has got corupted and could not boot. Is that possible to undo the resized partition diring ubuntu 16.4LTS installation. Any one can help me?

Comment: Do you have *data* on the Windows partition that are important to you and that were not backed up? (I'm talking about stuff like documents, pictures, videos, and so forth, that you cannot easily create or obtain again.) If so, please *stop using the installed Ubuntu system immediately to prevent any further data loss* and see [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/286181). Otherwise please [run Boot-Repair from a live USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Recommended_repair) and [edit] this with the BootInfo URL.

Comment: Partitions aren't some twiddling feature that can be undone - partitions are a *fundamental element* of the way your disk stores data. All changes are permanent. Any unwise change risks OS destruction and massive data loss. Experts always backup before partitioning for precisely these reasons. Many of us learned the hard way, too. Welcome to the club.

Answer (score 0):

Partition operations are in the most cases not reversible, so it is most likely that you have to setup Windows as new.

Only thing you can do is size both partitions from this point on before installing anything. And then install windows first then Ubuntu, this is the most likely way for it to work.

The next I write is not to get your hopes up but you can try with an Live image of Ubuntu to at least get some documents of the windows partition but that is with a BIG MAYBE. In almost all cases i have seen it was not possible. But at least worth a try.